# Сортировка массива. Нули, отрицательные, положительные

Tags: java

Имеется массив. Требуется осортировать его так, чтобы первые в массиве встали нули, после отрицательные, а самые последние оказались положительные цифры. Все это надо сделать в рамках одного массива

Comment: У вас что-то не получилось?

Comment: Рассматриваю массив с 0 элемента с последнего. Если последний элемент равен 0 и нулевой элемент не равен нулю, то заменяю и так далее. Но когда цикл с первого элемента доходит до последнего элемента, а цикл последнего наоборот, то эти элементы он опять заменяет местами. Т.е нули уже были расставлены, а цикл их продолжает менять местами пока не закончит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать такой вариант:

```
int a[] = {-8, 7, 0, 0, 6, 4, 17, -37, -178, -1, 0, 77};
a = IntStream.of(a).boxed().sorted(
    (x, y) -> x == 0 ? Integer.compare(x, Math.abs(y)) :
              y == 0 ? Integer.compare(Math.abs(x), y) :
              Integer.compare(x, y)
).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

В случае, если один из аргументов равен нулю - сравнивать его с абсолютным значением другого аргумента. Таким образом нули будут в самом начале, а остальные значения будут отсортированы как обычно.

В случае, если не нужно сортировать числа в каждой из групп, можно воспользоваться более простым вариантом:

```
a = IntStream.of(a).boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> i == 0 ? -1 : i > 0 ? 1 : 0))
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Ещё числа внутри трёх групп сортируются, а этого, вроде, не просили? Впрочем, я не уверен, является ли джавосортировка стабильной, так что этот вариант ничем не хуже.

Comment: Да, если не нужно сортировать в каждой группе, то всё ещё проще: `sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> i == 0 ? -1 : i > 0 ? 1 : 0))`

Comment: О, не знал про такую штуку :) Может, стоит в ответ её?

Answer (score 6):

https://ideone.com/QHVX8e

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Integer a[] = {-8, 7, 0, 0, 6, 4, 17, -37, -178, -1, 0, 77 };
    Arrays.sort(a, (x, y) -> x==0 ? y==0 ? 0 : -1 : x<0 ? y<0 ? 0 : y==0 ? 1 : -1 : y>0 ? 0 : 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```